# when is it required to add throws in Java?

Tags: java, exception, throws

in following example, Eclipse does not ask me to add ' throws EmptyStackException'

```
public E pop() {
  if (stack.isEmpty()) {
    throw new EmptyStackException();
  }
  ...
}
```

However, in following example, 'throws Exception' is required

```
public E pop() throws Exception {
  if(stack.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception();
...
}
```

Is there any specific rules on when should I add throws or not?

Comment: I suggest you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Keywords: Checked vs unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EmptyStackException` extends `RuntimeException` which is an unchecked exception while `Exception` is a checked exception.

Java only obliges you to catch checked exceptions. You can read more about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Answer (score 5):

This is the difference between [checked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) and [unchecked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).

A **checked exception** is part of a method signature, and is required to either be caught or declared to be thrown when the method is used.  They are subclasses of `Exception` themselves.

Some examples include a particular constructor of `Scanner`, or more formally, [`Scanner#<init>(File file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29).

Checked exceptions are declared to be thrown typically because **it is possible to recover from the exception**.  For instance, if you were to create a `Scanner` that read lines from a file, and the file didn't exist, what could you reasonably do besides ask them to re-specify the location?

An example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean found = false;
String path = sc.nextLine();
while(!found) {
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(path));
        found = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(path + " was not valid.  Please try again.");
        path = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

An **unchecked exception** is *not* part of a method signature, and may be thrown for any particular reason.  They are subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

One of the most common you'll encounter would be `NullPointerException`.  This particular exception could occur in the most innocuous of ways, such as:

```
Integer i = null;

System.out.println(i + 2); // NPE on unboxing
```

It is not typically expected for one to be able to recover from the exception; in layman's terms, something has gone wrong with the assumptions made about the flow of code.  That is to say, writing this is almost **certainly** a code smell:

```
Integer i = null;
try {
    System.out.println(i + 2);
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("i was null!?");
}
```

Most modern frameworks will allow you to specify a specific state that your application enters when such an error occurs - if it's a web driven application, you can have those sorts of runtime exceptions handled as a 500.

There is also `Error`, which is a special case of unchecked exceptions - you should **definitely not** recover from this, since it's indicated that something has gone terribly, terribly wrong with the JVM.

For instance, this is something you don't want to see:

```
public void recurse() {
    try {
        recurse();
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        System.out.println("We went in too deep.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare/handle `RuntimeException`s in a method signature, but, You have to declare/handle Checked Exception, if the method throws it and not handled inside the method.

In your case, `EmptyStackException` is a `RuntimeException`, so, you don't need to handle/declare it in the method, but `Exception` is a checked one, so, you must need to either handle it or declare it in the method signature